# Error when exporting math équation to pdf using Knitr

Tags: pdf, latex, knitr, r-markdown

I am trying to export my .rmd script to pdf. using Knitr (and Pandoc I guess). In this code, i have a math equation at line 116:

```
$$
\text{Sleep_cr}  = \frac{\text{Sleep_Data}-\boldsymbol\mu}{\boldsymbol{S}}
$$
```

when i Knit to pdf I get this error:

```
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
            $
l.274 \$ \text{Sleep_cr}

pandoc.exe: Error producing PDF
Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 43
```

If i delete the equation from the script everything works well and I can print the pdf.

How can i make this work?

I have Windows 10 and a newly downloaded MikTex.

Answer (score 1):

Underscores are special characters in LaTeX, and you have to escape them:

```
$$
\text{Sleep\_cr}  = \frac{\text{Sleep\_Data}-\boldsymbol\mu}{\boldsymbol{S}}
$$
```